# What?! I'm a damn billionaire!

Tags: riddle

> What Da Hell? You don't know who the heck I am!
>
> Well let me tell you some things to remember me
>
> A World-Class industry I own (I am the CEO of it :D)
>
> More than 10 billion dollars I have collected
>
> At least, that's what I believe so (too much money, too lazy to count)
>
> A famous billionaire I am ,with of course, the ability to fly
>
> And don't forget, a real beauty I have with me

Can you figure out who (or even what) I am?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps-

> Elon Musk

A World-Class industry I own (I am the CEO of it :D)

> He is the CEO of Tesla motors.

More than 10 billion dollars I have collected
At least, that's what I believe so (too much money, too lazy to count)

> Net worth about 20 Billion

A famous billionaire I am ,with of course, the ability to fly

> He is also founder of spaceX which designs and launches rockets and spacecraft

And don't forget, a real beauty I have with me

> not sure , could be about his ex wife Taluah Riley who is an actress

---

Seeing your earlier riddle it could also be -

> Tony Stark (Iron Man)

A World-Class industry I own (I am the CEO of it :D)

> He is the CEO of Stark Industry.

More than 10 billion dollars I have collected
At least, that's what I believe so (too much money, too lazy to count)

> Net worth about 12 billion

A famous billionaire I am ,with of course, the ability to fly

> He can fly with his iron man suit

And don't forget, a real beauty I have with me

> Pepper Potts

Comment: If you posted this as two separate answers, I would have +1ed both! :D

Comment: You convinced me both times

Comment: The second of these was my first guess on reading the puzzle. But it's tagged "wordplay" and I don't see any wordplay there, so I hope that isn't the answer.

Comment: It's actually the second one. Congrats (Will remove the wordplay tag, didn't know that it was inappropriate sorry )

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer but

> Donald Trump, is that you? XD

Comment: Mate, it's not Donald Trump though I should have thought of that . (+1) for the extreme creativity XD

Comment: I thought exactly this! Hahah! :D